# rrdtool graph: one graph line plotted incorectly

Tags: linux, bash, rrdtool

I'm trying to keep track of the CPU temperature and usage and then create a graph with the values. I used the rrdtool to store and create the graph. Here is the command I used to create:

```
rrdtool create "$temp_db" --step 10 DS:temp:GAUGE:30:0:200 DS:cpu:GAUGE:30:0:100 RRA:MAX:0.5:1:10080
```

then to insert values:

```
rrdtool update "$temp_db" --template temp:cpu N:"$cpuTemp":"$one"
```

if I query the data, it looks like this:

```
1501092070: 5.5000000000e+01 1.3890166000e-01
1501092080: 5.5571964700e+01 2.8151435200e-01
1501092090: 5.5571964700e+01 2.8151435200e-01
1501092100: 5.6000000000e+01 3.2340902500e-01
1501092110: 5.5471508500e+01 2.7357542500e-01
1501092120: 5.5000000000e+01 2.7103286800e-01
```

To create the graph I use this:

```
rrdtool graph cpu.png --slope-mode --full-size-mode --right-axis 1:0 \
    --x-grid MINUTE:1:MINUTE:10:MINUTE:10:0:%a/%H --width 900 --height 400  -s 'now - 1 hours' -e 'now' \
    DEF:TEMP=$temp_db:temp:MAX \
    DEF:CPU=$temp_db:cpu:MAX \
    LINE1:TEMP#0000FF:CPU_Temperature \
    LINE2:CPU#FF0000:CPU_Usage
```

The temperature line (temp) is showed corectly, but the the CPU usage (cpu) stays at 0. Here is how the graph looks like:

[image: rrdtool graph]
Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops, just realized that in my data one column is `e+01` and the other `e-01`

Comment: Yes, as I was going to say :).  Seems your CPU is being stored in a 0.00 - 1.00 scale rather than 0 - 100.  Just multiply it by 100 in your rrdgraph function and you'll get what you expect.